# Conditional case error in Codeigniter project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently, I am working on a Stocks Management Application. This is based on Codeigniter framework. The application's main operation is to manage "purchases" and "issues" like any of these type of applications.

02) order_status, a same column is used to record "purchases" and "issues" status in MySQL table & column named "supplier" records the supplier_id & officer_id as relevant.

03) Function that I used in Model as follows :

```
function issueDetailReport($id,$start,$end){
        $this->db->select('store_update_stock_details.item,
        CASE store_update_stock.order_status
        WHEN "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
        WHEN "issue" THEN store_officer.officer_name
        END AS supplier, *');

        $this->db->from('store_update_stock');
        $this->db->join('store_update_stock_details','store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id');      
        $this->db->join('store_officer','store_update_stock.supplier=store_officer.officer_id ');       
        $this->db->join('tbl_supplier','store_update_stock.supplier=tbl_supplier.supplier_id ');        
        $this->db->join('store_item','store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status='1' and store_item.item_id=$id");
        if($start!=NULL && $end!=NULL)
        $this->db->where("store_update_stock.billed_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");     
        $this->db->order_by('store_update_stock.purchased_date','DESC');
        $q=$this->db->get();
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

04) And View as follows :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%">
        <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>In Num</th>                   
                    <th class="text-left">Received / Issued </th>
                    <th class="text-left">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Sub Total</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $sub_total=0;
                $total=0;
                $no=1;
                $totalqty=0;
                if(!empty($issueDetail)){
                    foreach ($issueDetail as $rows){
                        $sub_total=(-1)*$rows->qty*$rows->unit_price;
                        $total=$total+$sub_total;
                        $qty_sub_total=(-1)*$rows->qty;
                        $totalqty=$totalqty+$qty_sub_total;
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$no++?></td>             
                        <td class="text-left"><?=$rows->supplier_name / officer_name?></td>                 

                        <td class="text-left"><?=$rows->purchased_date?></td>                       
                        <td class="text-right"><?=(-1)*$rows->qty?></td>                                
                        <td class="text-right"><?=$rows->unit_price?></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><?=number_format($sub_total,2)?></td>

                    </tr>
                <?php

                    }
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1" class="text-left">Total </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="text-right" > <?=$totalqty?></th>
                        <th></th>

                        <th class="text-right" > <?=number_format($total,2)?></th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
```

05) When executing the View, the following error has fired.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`officer_name` `END` AS `supplier` FROM `store_update_stock` JOIN `store_update_stoc' at line 1

SELECT `store_update_stock_details`.`item`, `CASE store_update_stock`.`order_status WHEN "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier`.`supplier_name WHEN "issue" THEN store_officer`.`officer_name` `END`, `FALSE` FROM `store_update_stock` JOIN `store_update_stock_details` ON `store_update_stock`.`update_stock_id`=`store_update_stock_details`.`update_stock_id` JOIN `store_officer` ON `store_update_stock`.`supplier`=`store_officer`.`officer_id` JOIN `tbl_supplier` ON `store_update_stock`.`supplier`=`tbl_supplier`.`supplier_id` INNER JOIN `store_item` ON `store_update_stock_details`.`item`=`store_item`.`item_id` WHERE `store_update_stock`.`status` = '1' and `store_item`.`item_id` = 3 ORDER BY `store_update_stock`.`purchased_date` DESC

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/doastores/application/models/Report_model.php

Line Number: 112

06) But the query is working fine in PhPMyAdmin. I can not understand what may be going wrong in this point. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas. Hopefully one or the other will solve the problem.

Looking at the error message's display of the query statement I see that the "supplier" alias is missing as well as the all-fields wildcard (*). This often points to Query Builder having a hard time escaping values and identifiers.

So the first thing to try is to turn off "escaping" for the `select()` statement which is done by passing `FALSE` as the second argument. This is safe enough as there is no user input involved.

The second thing to try is to change the string for the `select` statement by using double quotes to define the whole and single-quotes around *purchase* and *issue*.

Doing those two things the code is now like this.

```
$this->db->select("store_update_stock_details.item,
CASE store_update_stock.order_status
  WHEN 'purchase' THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
  WHEN 'issue' THEN store_officer.officer_name
END AS supplier, *", false);
```